# Quarkus testing- static members in test utils wiped out

Tags: testing, quarkus

I am attempting to shave some time off my tests in Quarkus by saving off resources in static members of utilities in my `test` sources. Examples here being test containers and a Selenium web driver. I am saving these off so that ideally between tests/ profile changes, I can keep the same instances of these services that took a long time to instantiate.

However, it seems that when the tests re-run the test server, the static members that hold these are wiped out, thus killing the benefits I was trying to achieve.

How can I keep these static members from being wiped out, or otherwise keep some data between server instances?

Example of where I am trying to do this:

https://github.com/Epic-Breakfast-Productions/OpenQuarterMaster/blob/main/software/open-qm-base-station/src/test/java/com/ebp/openQuarterMaster/baseStation/testResources/lifecycleManagers/TestResourceLifecycleManager.java

```
public class TestResourceLifecycleManager implements QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager {
    public static final String EXTERNAL_AUTH_ARG = "externalAuth";

    private static MongoDBContainer MONGO_EXE = null;
    private static KeycloakContainer KEYCLOAK_CONTAINER = null;

    ...
```

In this example, I realize the test resources might not get torn down as planned, but ideally that could be handled in a lifecycle event, but am still working on why the static members disappear. One step at a time.

Comment: Mind adding some sample code that you have been using?

Comment: Added sample code, thanks

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. You are seeing this because the implementations of `QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager` are loaded from different classloaders. Unfortunately there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: I would accept this, but I am also seeing this in other classes (not extending `QTRLM`), is there a context of class that can get around this?

Comment: What other classes?